# Enviar correo Según Fecha

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, proporcionándome consejos, tips, o bien guiarme para lograr lo siguiente:
Necesito enviar un correo a la persona que creo la solicitud cuando faltan 2 semanas para que comience la fecha inicial del curso, hasta ahora solo tengo la siguiente consulta en mi base de datos pero realmente no se como lograr lo que necesito, en mi servidor ya tengo PHPMailer y envío correos en otros casos y funciona sin problemas.

```
SELECT dd_mm_inicio, if((dd_mm_inicio - INTERVAL 2 WEEK) = CURDATE(), "TRUE", "FALSE")
  FROM servicio where id_formulario_1=7
```

Cuando falten exactamente 2 semanas para la fecha de inicio se envíe correo a las 9:00 am, solo ese día.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
SELECT * FROM servicio where (dd_mm_inicio - INTERVAL 2 WEEK) = CURDATE()
```

ya que lo unico que necesitas es validar que sea antes de las 2 semanas
si deseas validar otro campo bastaria con agregarselo con:

```
SELECT * FROM servicio where
(dd_mm_inicio - INTERVAL 2 WEEK) = CURDATE() and id_formulario_1=7
```

ahora para ejecutarlo solo bastaria con:

```
$consulta ="SELECT * FROM servicio where (dd_mm_inicio - INTERVAL 2 WEEK) = CURDATE()";

if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {
    while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
         $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
         $mail->Subject = 'inica el curso el dia: '.$fila["dd_mm_inicio"];
         $mail->Body    = 'incia el curso!';
         $mail->send();
         // limpiamos la direcciones si no enviara nuevamente a los anteriores
         $mail->clearAddresses();
         $mail->clearAttachments();
    }

    /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
    $resultado->free();
}
```

ahora solo bastaria agregarlo a un crontab o al programador de tareas de windows

para que se ejecute 1 o 2 veces al dia.

Comment: Una consulta, estoy creando un archivo .sh para ejecutarlo con crontab, mi consulta es si el codigo PHP en tu respuesta, funcionara en el archivo .sh????

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es hacer una tarea programada que se ejecute todos los días a las 9:00am y que revise si existen en tu tabla de cursos alguno que falte 2 semanas para empezar y así notificar.

La forma mas común de hacer esto es usando crontab, te dejo un enlace con todo lo que necesitas saber para montarlo:

https://geekflare.com/es/crontab-linux-with-real-time-examples-and-tools/

**Resumiendo:**

- crontab -e
- Agregar esta linea: 0 9 * * * /scripts/job.sh <- es el script que busca los casos y envía los emails necesarios.
- crontab -l (para verificar que se ha creado)

Espero haber ayudado.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Prueba la función de fecha:

```
<small>Este email fue enviado a: **[<?php echo date("dd/M/YY HH:i:s");]**</small>
```

puedes consultar los diferentes formatos en

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, pero no es lo que necesito

Comment: Tengo un curso que tiene fecha de inicio y lo que necesito es que cuando falten 2 semanas para el inicio se envíe correo de forma automática.